# Yii2 Girdview User Ordered Columns

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to make one of our GridView modules customisable for our team. I have been able to allow the users the show and hide certain columns using `'visible'=> if ( $data->field_name == "some_value" ) ? true : false,`

I want to the users to be able to order the columns to their preference, any idea on how I can accomplish this please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Gridview columns are sorteable but if you want to add default sorting you can try this with your provider

```
 $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
            'product_name' => [
                'asc' => ['product_name' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['product_name' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_ASC
            ],
            'date' => [
                'asc' => ['date' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['date' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_ASC,
            ],
        ],
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'date' => SORT_ASC
        ]
    ]);
```